# IronPython.dll - which one to use?

Tags: python, .net, ironpython

I want to add a reference to IronPython.dll to my project.

I found this dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\ and different dll's for different Net versions in C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Platforms\ . What is the difference between these dll's and which one shall I use?

The same story with Microsoft.Scripting.dll & Co.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assemblies in the root (`C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\`) are for `ipy.exe` to use. Apps that embed IronPython should use the ones in the appropriate Platform directory (or NuGet, which will pick the right ones automatically).

*For now*, the assemblies in the root are identical to the ones in `Platforms\net40`, but that is not in any way guaranteed and will almost certainly change in the future.